# Apply CSS only if first or last occurence of a class

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML `table` with many rows

```
 ________________________
|_1______________________|
|_2______________________|
|_3______________________|
|_4______________________|
|_5______________________|
```

These rows are expandable, and a user might expand multiple of them

```
 ________________________
|_1______________________|
| 2                      |
| border-top             |
| border-bottom          |
|________________________|
|_3______________________|
| 4 ...                  |
```

I need to highlight with `border-top` and `border-bottom` the expanded rows.

However, if two adjacent rows are expanded, the `border-bottom` of the above one merges with the `border-top` of the below one.
Having a border of `1px` results `1px + 1px`, which I don't want.

Is this situation avoidable using CSS selectors?

Comment: Show us code, not ascii art.

Comment: You should at-least write html code. then we can see possible solution.

Comment: @TahirShahzad samb102 provided the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I well understood: if 2 adjacents rows are open, the second row should hides its top-border to avoid a double border ?

You can perform this with the sibling operator `+`.

```
.row-expanded + .row-expanded {
  border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this CSS combinator. Can different classes be mixed?

Comment: Of course. See also `>` and `~` selectors which are very useful.

Comment: Thank you. The general sibling combinator (tilde) is another one I'll use.